# Pong Ball Collision Problems

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Recently, I've started making the Pong game, because the tutorial I'm following told me I can make simple games now.

I guess Pong isn't as simple as I thought, then.

First of all, here's the code:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;




Game::Game(MainWindow& wnd)
    :
    wnd(wnd),
    gfx(wnd)
{
}

void Game::Go()
{
    gfx.BeginFrame();
    UpdateModel();
    ComposeFrame();
    gfx.EndFrame();
}

void Game::UpdateModel()
{
    ///Moves player paddles
    MovePaddle();
    ///Checks if player paddles are inside the given parameters.
    LeftPlayerY = WallInsideBorder(LeftPlayerY);
    RightPlayerY = WallInsideBorder(RightPlayerY);
    PongBallPhysics();
    IsGoal();

}

void Game::ComposeFrame()
{

    DrawBall(BallX, BallY, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    DrawWall(LeftPlayerX, LeftPlayerY);
    DrawWall(RightPlayerX, RightPlayerY);
    DrawThePixelatedWall();
    DrawScoreboard();

}

///Draws the Pongball
void Game::DrawBall(int BallX, int BallY, int BallRed, int BallGreen, int BallBlue)
{
    ///Middle layer of pixels
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX, BallY, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX + 1, BallY, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX + 2, BallY, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX + 3, BallY, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX - 1, BallY, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX - 2, BallY, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX - 3, BallY, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    ///Layer of Pixels above middle layer
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX - 3, BallY - 1, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX - 2, BallY - 1, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX - 1, BallY - 1, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX, BallY - 1, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX + 1, BallY - 1, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX + 2, BallY - 1, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX + 3, BallY - 1, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    ///Layer of Pixels beneath top layer
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX - 2, BallY - 2, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX - 1, BallY - 2, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX, BallY - 2, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX + 1, BallY - 2, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX + 2, BallY - 2, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    ///Top Layer
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX - 1, BallY - 3, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX, BallY - 3, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX + 1, BallY - 3, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    ///Layer beneath middle layer
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX - 3, BallY + 1, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX - 2, BallY + 1, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX - 1, BallY + 1, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX, BallY + 1, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX + 1, BallY + 1, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX + 2, BallY + 1, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX + 3, BallY + 1, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    ///Layer above bottom layer
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX - 2, BallY + 2, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX - 1, BallY + 2, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX, BallY + 2, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX + 1, BallY + 2, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX + 2, BallY + 2, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    ///Bottom layer
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX - 1, BallY + 3, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX, BallY + 3, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);
    gfx.PutPixel(BallX + 1, BallY + 3, BallRed, BallGreen, BallBlue);



}
///Draws the walls for the players (100 pixels tall)
void Game::DrawWall(int XCoordinate, int YCoordinate)
{
    if (XCoordinate == LeftPlayerX)
    {
        for (int i = -50; i <= 50; ++i)
        {
            gfx.PutPixel(XCoordinate, YCoordinate + i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(XCoordinate - 1, YCoordinate + i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(XCoordinate - 2, YCoordinate + i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(XCoordinate - 3, YCoordinate + i, 255, 255, 255);
        }
    }

    if (XCoordinate == RightPlayerX)
    {
        for (int i = -50; i <= 50; ++i)
        {
            gfx.PutPixel(XCoordinate, YCoordinate + i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(XCoordinate + 1, YCoordinate + i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(XCoordinate + 2, YCoordinate + i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(XCoordinate + 3, YCoordinate + i, 255, 255, 255);
        }
    }
}
///Draws the boundary between the player fields
void Game::DrawThePixelatedWall()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 597; i = i + 3)
    {
        gfx.PutPixel(399, i, 255, 255, 255);
    }
}
///Draws the scoreboard.
void Game::DrawScoreboard()
{
    switch (LeftPlayerScore) {
    case 0:
        for (int i = 6; i <= 50; ++i)
        {
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + 6, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + 5, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 - 5, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 - 6, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + 7, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 - 7, i, 255, 255, 255);
        }
        for (int i = -4; i <= 6; ++i)
        {
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + i, 6, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + i, 7, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + i, 8, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + i, 50, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + i, 49, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + i, 48, 255, 255, 255);
        }


        break;

    case 1:
        for (int i = 6; i <= 50; ++i)
        {
            gfx.PutPixel(320, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + 1, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 - 1, i, 255, 255, 255);
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        break;

    case 3:
        break;

    case 4:
        break;

    case 5:
        break;

    case 6:
        break;

    case 7:
        break;

    case 8:
        for (int i = 6; i <= 50; ++i)
        {
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + 6, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + 5, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 - 5, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 - 6, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + 7, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 - 7, i, 255, 255, 255);
        }
        for (int i = -4; i <= 6; ++i)
        {
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + i, 6, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + i, 7, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + i, 8, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + i, 50, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + i, 49, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + i, 48, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + i, 27, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(320 + i, 28, 255, 255, 255);
        }

        break;

    case 9:
        break;

    case 10:
        break;

    }
    switch (RightPlayerScore) {
    case 0:
        for (int i = 6; i <= 50; ++i)
        {
            gfx.PutPixel(478 + 6, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(478 + 5, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(478 - 5, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(478 - 6, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(478 + 7, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(478 - 7, i, 255, 255, 255);
        }
        for (int i = -4; i <= 6; ++i)
        {
            gfx.PutPixel(478 + i, 6, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(478 + i, 7, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(478 + i, 8, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(478 + i, 50, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(478 + i, 49, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(478 + i, 48, 255, 255, 255);
        }
        break;

    case 1:
        for (int i = 6; i <= 50; ++i)
        {
            gfx.PutPixel(478, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(478 + 1, i, 255, 255, 255);
            gfx.PutPixel(478 - 1, i, 255, 255, 255);
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        break;

    case 3:
        break;

    case 4:
        break;

    case 5:
        break;

    case 6:
        break;

    case 7:
        break;

    case 8:
        break;

    case 9:
        break;

    case 10:
        break;

    }
}
///Checks if Walls are inside
int Game::WallInsideBorder(int YCoordinate)
{
    if (YCoordinate + 50 >= gfx.ScreenHeight)
    {
        return gfx.ScreenHeight - 51;
    }
    if (YCoordinate - 50 < 0)
    {
        return 51;
    }
    return YCoordinate;
}
///Pong Ball physics :D
void Game::PongBallPhysics()
{
    BallX = BallX + BallVX;
    BallY = BallY + BallVY;
    ///Sets initial VX and VY
    if (FirstTime)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        BallY = rand() % 599;
        BallVX = rand() % 4 + 1;
        srand(time(NULL));
        BallVY = rand() % 4 + 1;
        FirstTime = false;
    }
    /// Touching top or bottom?
    if (BallY - 3 < 0)
    {
        DoBounceCalculation();
        BallY = 3;
    }
    if (BallY + 3 > 599)
    {
        DoBounceCalculation();
        BallY = 595;
    }
    ///Touching a wall?
    /// ERROR, BallVX goes PAST LeftPlayerX/RightPlayerX!
    IsTouchingWall();

}
///Makes the angle be the same as when it hit the wall/boundary.Looked at and is working
void Game::DoBounceCalculation()
{
    BallVY = -BallVY;
} 
///Swaps two variables, looked at and should be working
void Game::Swap(int &x, int &y)
{
    int SwapVariable = x;
    x = y;
    y = SwapVariable;
}
///Checks if ball is in opponent's goal, looked at and is working
void Game::IsGoal()
{
    if (BallX - 3 <= 0)
    {
        RightPlayerScore++;
        BallX = 399;
        FirstTime = true;
    }
    if (BallX + 3 >= gfx.ScreenWidth)
    {
        LeftPlayerScore++;
        BallX = 399;
        FirstTime = true;
    }
}
///Moves player walls, looked at and is working
void Game::MovePaddle()
{
    if (wnd.kbd.KeyIsPressed(0x57))
    {
        LeftPlayerY = LeftPlayerY - 3;
    }
    if (wnd.kbd.KeyIsPressed(0x53))
    {
        LeftPlayerY = LeftPlayerY + 3;
    }
    if (wnd.kbd.KeyIsPressed(0x49))
    {
        RightPlayerY = RightPlayerY - 3;
    }
    if (wnd.kbd.KeyIsPressed(0x4B))
    {
        RightPlayerY = RightPlayerY + 3;
    }
}
///Checks if Ball is touching Player paddles and changes velocity accordingly, this is bwoke man, check it
void Game::IsTouchingWall()
{
    // if-statement that checks if the ball is gonna hit the paddle in the next frame.
    // The problem is, that VX or VY skip the pixels between (when they're set to anything higher than 1)
    // So that they jump other the paddle.
}
```

And here's the header file if you're interested.

```
#pragma once

#include "Keyboard.h"
#include "Mouse.h"
#include "Graphics.h"

class Game
{
public:
    Game(class MainWindow& wnd);
    Game(const Game&) = delete;
    Game& operator=(const Game&) = delete;
    void Go();
private:
    void ComposeFrame();
    void UpdateModel();
    /********************************/
    /*  User Functions              */
    void DrawBall(int BallX, int BallY, int BallRed, int BallGreen, int BallBlue);
    void DrawWall(int XCoordinate, int YCoordinate);
    void DrawThePixelatedWall();
    void DrawScoreboard();
    int WallInsideBorder(int YCoordinate);
    void PongBallPhysics();
    void DoBounceCalculation();
    void Swap(int& x, int& y);
    void IsGoal();
    void MovePaddle();
    void IsTouchingWall();

    /********************************/
private:
    MainWindow& wnd;
    Graphics gfx;
    /********************************/
    /*  User Variables              */
    int BallVX = 0;
    int BallVY = 0;
    int BallX = 399;
    int BallY = 0;
    int BallRed = 255;
    int BallGreen = 255;
    int BallBlue = 255;
    const int LeftPlayerX = 100;
    int LeftPlayerY = 299;
    const int RightPlayerX = 700;
    int RightPlayerY = 299;
    int LeftPlayerScore = 0;
    int RightPlayerScore = 0;
    bool FirstTime = true;

    /********************************/
};
```

If you aren't familiar with the Pong game click [here](http://www.ponggame.org/).
Basically, in Pong, you try to get the Pongball past the players paddle, and need to defend your side of the field. You "defend" by moving your paddle in the way of the Pongball, which launches it back at your opponent in a random direction.

The problem I'm facing right now, is that I can't make the Pongball's hitbox hit the hitboxes of the players. This is because the Pongball moves by adding the "accelerators" to the coordinates.

> BallX = BallX + BallVX;
>    BallY = BallY + BallVY;

Which means it can skip over the hitboxes of the paddles, not colliding with the paddle. This approach was wrong anyways, since changing the direction of the Pongball by accelerating into different directions makes the Pongball faster, too.

I should add that the gfx.PutPixel() function was given to me by the tutorial, and it works like this: gfx.PutPixel(XCoordinate, YCoordinate, Red Value, Green Value, Blue Value); , the Draw functions aren't causing any problems as far as I know, anyways, so you should probably skip over them.

My question to you guys is:
*How should I detect that the Pongball would be colliding with the paddle?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Collision detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection) in games in general is not such a trivial task. But for a simplest case in pong, where you can disregard sizes of paddles and ball, it is sufficient to intersect ball trajectory with paddle. In other words, you can take two line segments: first from position of the ball in the previous frame to the current ball position and second from one end of the paddle to another, and bounce the ball if they do intersect.

Comment: This sounds extremely stupid of me, but how would I calculate if the two lines intersect? And wouldn't I get the problem that the ball would bounce away a fair bit away from the actual paddle? Very interesting though!

Comment: [Here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/) is one example. For the ball bouncing you can place ball at the point of intersection (eliminate clipping) and reflect/scale velocity vector. At least some basic geometry/linear algebra is essential for gamedev though. [There are some good books](https://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/1482250926)  for not math-savvy.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had come to that conclusion too when I saw your post, but didn't know how to calculate that.